# 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before add

Tags: flash

Whats wrong with my code? I'm getting this error in adobe flash:

```
Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 2, Line 2, Column 13    1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before add.
```

This is the code:

```
// create random speed and xpos for this snowflake
set ("xpos" add c], random(200));
set ("speed" add c], Number(random(4))+2);
// duplicae a snowflake
flake0.duplicateMovieClip ("flake" add c, c);
// set x position and random size
this["flake" add c]._x = eval("xpos" add c);
size = Number(random(50))+25;
this["flake" add c]._xscale = size;
this["flake" add c]._yscale = size;
//move each snowflake down by its speed;
for(i=1;i<=maxflakes;i++) {
    this["flake" add i]._y = this["flake" add i]._y + eval("speed" add i);
    i = i+1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
set ("xpos" add c], random(200));
```

This is incorrect. Either there will be a comma after "xpos" or you should close the parentheses.

Comment: could you help me with corrected code. i have ZERO knowledge in coding. i just copied it from somewhere and am tryiing to run to see how it works